# Unable to show a set is open/closed

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Im struggling with how to show a set is open or closed.. worse is i have a test on this in a few days..

Here's an example, let $S = [(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon \frac{x}{y} \leq 7 ] $

I have to show whether its open, closed or neither. I started by defining a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y} - 7$ and then trying to find out something about $f^{-1}(S)$ and if its an open set. But im having trouble with this. I'm after some help and a general method to help me in future decide whether a set is open/closed/neeither.

Comment: The answer of this depends on the definition of $\frac{x}{0}$. And on the definition of $\frac{0}{0}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picture you set:

1. For $\frac xy$ to be defined, $\{y=0\}$ must not be in the set
2. If $y>0$, the condition becomes $\frac xy \le 7 \Rightarrow\underline{\phantom{x\le 7}}$
3. If $y<0$, the condition becomes $\frac xy \le 7 \Rightarrow\underline{\phantom{x\ge 7}}$
4. Finally, the set can be written as: $S = \{(x,y)| \underline{\phantom{y>0 \wedge x\le 7}}\} \cup \{(x,y)|\underline{\phantom{y<0 \wedge x\ge 7}}\}$

What can you say about this?

---

Answers:

> 2.: $\frac xy\le 7 \Rightarrow x\le 7$
>  3.: $\frac xy\le 7 \Rightarrow x\ge 7$
>  4.: $\{(x,y)| y>0 \wedge x\le 7\} \cup \{(x,y)|y<0 \wedge x\ge 7\}$

Comment: Unfortunately i typed the question wrong, its actually $\frac{x}{y} \leq 7 $ . How does that change the set?

Comment: @user65972 My approach still works. Try to apply it and include your results in the question; then I will see if it is correct.

Comment: Thank You, so Its neither open or closed?

Comment: Also, is this a general method for finding whether a set is open/closed?

Comment: @user65972 Yes to both.